# Proving altitude and side inequalities

Tags: geometry

In an acute-angled triangle ABC, AB < AC, BD and CE are the altitudes. Prove that
$AB^2 + CE^2 < AC^2 + BD^2$

and

$AB^n + CE^n < AC^n + BD^n$ for positive integers n

I have already found BD < CE and AD < AE but cannot seem to find more information. I already tried using the pythagorean and triangle areas to try and prove it.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$A=\frac{ch_c}{2}$$ and $$A=\frac {bh_b}{2}$$ so we have to Show that

$$b^2+\frac{4A^2}{b^2}<b^2+\frac{4A^2}{c^2}$$
this is equivalent to

$$(b^2-c^2)(1-\frac{4A^2}{b^2c^2})>0$$
this is true since we have $$c<b$$ and $$A=\frac{1}{2}bc\sin(\gamma)\le \frac{bc}{2}$$
and your second inequality is equivalent to

$$(b^n-c^n)\left(1-\frac{(2A)^n}{(bc)^n}\right)>0$$
the rest is for you!